# ng-repeat declared variable not getting updated in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have declared a $scope variable in my controller:

```
$scope.filteredPayments = [];
```

I have an `ng-repeat` in my HTML that runs the following:

```
ng-repeat="payment in filteredPayments = payments"
```

`payments` is populated asynch from Parse. It works correctly and populates my table accordingly.

The following watch does not fire either:

```
$scope.$watch('filteredPayments', function(newValues) {
    console.log(newValues);
}
```

Why is `filteredPayments` not being updated in my controller especially since when I have no filters defined it shows all of the payments I have in my backend?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean here? All I see is you have set and empty scope variable and ran it through a repeat. Where are you putting items in that variable for the repeat? What is suppose to be happening here?

Comment: @ajmajmajma I improved the description and made the code even simpler.

Comment: What is the purpose of filteredPayments = payments in the repeat?

Comment: I have a watch on filteredPayments to run some code on updates. I have updated the description with that watch code. The watch itself isn't firing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to bind payments to filter payments in the ng-repeat like

```
filteredPayments = payments
```

What you should do is update the $scope.filteredPayments, as that is what the repeat is being run upon. So maybe a $q promise from your parse (or whatever you prefer) and then set. Something along the lines of this (again I don't know exactly how you get your data back.

```
 //retrieve new data

 .then(function(newData){

  $scope.filteredPayments = newData;
  });
```

Or maybe something simple, as long as you are sure the payments variable is updated like :

```
$scope.filteredPayments = payments;
```

Comment: I have this ng-repeat:

ng-repeat="payment in filteredPayments = (payments | filter:equivalencyFilter | filter:search.value)"

I want to have filteredPayments hold the payments that are filtered and then run some code on that data. That is why I have setup filteredPayments and the $watch. I don't understand why it isn't firing.

Comment: As I was saying before - the filters and everything work correctly. My table is correctly updated when my data is filtered. For some reason I cannot access that filtered data using $scope.filteredPayments in my controller. My $watch doesn't fire.

Comment: @Niraj because you are binding it only in the scope of the repeat, you should let angular work it's magic and use a method as I have listed above. The watch itself is not going to fire because filteredPayments is not actually changing in that scope. You are using kind of a "hack" with filteredPayments = payments

Comment: Is there a way to assign filteredPayments to the parent scoped variable?

Comment: @Niraj I wouldn't want to dig into that, you are going around the way angular has been set up to work. You should try to set up your repeat as "payment in filteredPayments" and assign in the controller whatever you need to filteredPayments, as it is bound to the repeat. You shouldn't have to add extra watches to a scope var you are using as an ng-repeat item, as angular already does that for you.

Comment: I will definitely do that. Thank you so much for your help!